# MySQL like doesn't like `\`?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of strings. They are all absolute paths (no relative at the moment) and they all start with `\` (windows folder separator)

When I do a query with a like using

```
select * from list where name like @foo
```

and foo is

```
@"\a" + %
```

I get no results. If I use `%\a%` I get results. I then tried using mysql command line and wrote

```
where name like '\a%' limit 10;
```

I get no results there as well unless i write `%\a%`. Why doesn't it like `\`? and how do i have a string start with `\a`? I don't want to get `\random\apples\file` when I am expecting `\apples\file`

Comment: It sounds like an escaping issue. Have you tried doubling the backslash, i.e. `@"\\a" + %`?

Comment: You should know that the backslash is used for escaping...

Comment: @rekire: Shouldnt the fact that i'm putting the value through a parameter escape the value for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `\` is the escaping character .

Try replacing it with `\\` instead

[Special Character Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences)

Comment: See - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences

Comment: seriously what the hell!? Very relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614291/how-do-i-escape-mysql-properly

Answer (score 1):

try this

\ is a sign which escapes the next sign.. sometimes used to escape a \" quote or the backslash itself

> where name like '\\a%' limit 10;

Comment: oops i forgot that its \ in the cli however wtf i thought parameter values would escape this