# How do I escape mysql properly?

Tags: .net, mysql

I just found out that if i write

```
select * from tbl where name like @foo
```

Then add foo as a parameter with the value `\a` (user data) that it will not escape it correctly. What the hell!?! It wants `\\a`. I can't help but feel i'm  open to a sql inject even though i am using parameters.

How do I escape the user data in variables correctly? I'm using mysql on C# with using dapper.net

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper) to see if it's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tadman: Nah I don't like stored procedures

Comment: That seems to be talking about dynamic parameters, which is sometimes pretty much the same thing depending on your ORM. There's nothing to "like" about stored procedures. Just as you're supposed to eat your vegetables, follow best practices.

Comment: @tadman: Alright but I still have no idea how to escape user data

Answer (score 0):

For like statements I add in this

```
.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"_", @"\_").Replace(@"%", @"\%")
```